# Why does using a column name directly in HQL only work sometimes?

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, hql

I have two HQL queries I am using for a quick-and-dirty unit test. The first looks somewhat like this:

```
from Foo where SOME_FOREIGN_KEY = 42
```

The second looks like this:

```
from Foo as foo
 inner join foo.Bar as bar
 where foo.SOME_FOREIGN_KEY = 42
```

The SOME_FOREIGN_KEY column is not the name of something that Hibernate knows is mapped.

For some reason, the first HQL query works, but the second one does not.

My goal here is to get the second version to work, without traversing the object graph to the object identified by the foreign key. For this test, I have a known ID and I only want the objects related to that ID. The object itself on the other end of the relationship is irrelevant. Is this possible?

Comment: Note, I am tagging this as both "nhibernate" and "hibernate" in case this applies to both (as it is an HQL question), but I am actually using NHibernate.

Comment: Is SOME_FOREIGN_KEY actual key to BAR table?

Comment: SOME_FOREIGN_KEY is a foreign key to a separate table that is not in the query.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> For some reason, the first HQL query works, but the second one does not.

When you use something that isn't known by Hibernate in the `WHERE` clause of an HQL query (e.g. a function that is not registered in the SQL dialect), Hibernate acts smartly and **passes it directly to the database**.

In other words, assuming `Foo` is mapped on `TABLE_FOO`, the following HQL

```
from Foo where SOME_FOREIGN_KEY = 42
```

is translated into the following SQL

```
SELECT FROM TABLE_FOO WHERE SOME_FOREIGN_KEY = 42
```

And works if `TABLE_FOO` actually has a `SOME_FOREIGN_KEY` column.

However, when using an alias like in the second example:

```
from Foo as foo where foo.SOME_FOREIGN_KEY = 42
```

Hibernate tries to resolve `SOME_FOREIGN_KEY` as **a property** of the `Foo` entity, and this obviously fails.

> My goal here is to get the second version to work, without traversing the object graph to the object identified by the foreign key.

It won't if you prefix the column with the alias. So the following should work:

```
from Foo as foo
 inner join foo.Bar as bar
 where SOME_FOREIGN_KEY = 42
```

But honestly, I don't understand why you don't want to use a path expression and I would advice against using the above solution. One of the the point of HQL is to abstract the table and column names and you would be totally defeating this goal here.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that the HQL I was using was not the correct way to do it, especially in light of your response. (I would be introducing a database-specific dependency.) In fact, HQL is, as I said, just a quick-and-dirty test; nothing remotely production.

Answer (score 1):

So Foo in first example is without alias and in second it is. This means that in second example Hibernate is looking for property of the 'foo'. This should be the answer.

Maybe this will work:

```
      select  f
      from    Foo f
      inner join f.Bar bar
      where   f.SomeForeignKeyId = 42
```

SomeForeignKeyId is property mapped to SOME_FOREIGN_KEY, either way you will have to do this through Id field of referencing entity.

Also fetching Foo as in first example, should work just fine, depending on your mapping. So if in your mapping you have Eager fetching, that should work as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, I can understand why there might be a difference here. I'm trying to figure out how to get the 2nd version to work despite that...

Comment: See my example. Maybe it can help.

Comment: Thanks; this is helpful, and it solved my problem, though not quite the way I expected. I have the column mapped like <many-to-one name="SomeForeignKeyId" .../> *(using your example). This worked. I still want to understand why using the column name works in some cases, and not in others, though.

Comment: I would suggest to run NProf or set "show_sql" to see SQL generated out of two different queries, maybe this can bring something interesting to the table.