# use column name instead of entity property in JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have `JPQL/Hibernate` for `DA` layer.
I have a table as following:

```
CREATE TABLE Log_Tbl
(
id number,
name varchar2(30),
);
```

and I have a entity for above table as following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Log_Tbl")
public class ELog
{
  @Column(name = "id")
  private long entity_id;

  @Column(name = "name") 
  private String entity_name;
}
```

and map `Log` entity to `Log_Tbl` table by `jpa`;
I have two `JPQL` queries as following:

- `select ELog from ELog where entity_name  = 'Job'`
- `select ELog from ELog where name  = 'Job'`

Both queries returned the correct result. My question is:

Why does the second query return the correct result although I used the column name instead of the `entity_name` property?

Comment: second is illegal JPQL and non-portable.

Comment: @NeilStockton but second query executed and answered fine also

Comment: and as I said, it is invalid JPQL, and if it works in your JPA implementation then you can't rely on it in ANY other

Comment: @NeilStockton I means is your answer, really it is dependent to `JPA` implementation? (in my situation its `Hibernate`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3918035/4074715) to a similar (if not duplicate) question

> When you use something that isn't known by Hibernate in the WHERE clause of an HQL query (e.g. a function that is not registered in the SQL dialect), Hibernate acts smartly and passes it directly to the database.

So, it does work but it is vendor specific and probably wouldn't work if you switched your JPA implementation.

Comment: Yes, My goal is ensure that it is vendor specific and maybe not worked on another `JPA` implementations.